# Python: I have a value and am having trouble getting it to display back to the text field

Tags: python, tkinter

I build a form from some fields.  I use the first value entered in the form to get results of the other fields.

```
 from tkinter import *
    fields = ('no1','no2')

    def makeform(root, fields):

       global PN

       for field in fields:
         row = Frame(root)
         lab = Label(row, width=30, text=field, anchor='w')
         ent = Entry(row)
         row.pack(side=TOP, fill=X, padx=5, pady=5)
         lab.pack(side=LEFT)
         ent.pack(side=RIGHT, expand=YES, fill=X)
         PN.append((field, ent))
```

I pass a function the 'no1' value entered by the user and then it returns a result that I want to show in the text field created for 'no2'

I have the value returned by a function and am trying to get it to be displayed back into a text field.

Two things: I want to be able to do this for multiple fields and multiple values.  The next thing is to get the values that the user inputs and then post them back to a file.

Any help?

Comment: [_Without a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example, it is hard to know what is wrong_](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/).

Comment: I was able to get what I needed by using

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get what I needed by using the list PN in a for loop to get the field names' values and store them as a variable for display:

```
          for entry in PN:
           field = entry[0]
           texta = returnquery['ownerName']
           textb = returnquery['county']
```